# Is there a way to require an expert eye on a complex question

Tags: discussion, chat, questions, bounties, users

It is a question about *complexity* (the computer science term). And I'd really like to have an expert look at the question and the 2 voted answers. The question has been there for a while (2 days), so I wonder if it will get fixed someday.

The *complexity* concept is complex, and I really feel bad when a *wrong* answer gets accepted, or has a higher score than a correct one. Really. It's not (only) the rep points;  if the wrong answer is down-voted, the average reader will at least know that the answer is possibly not relevant.

So, is there a way to raise the hand and call for an expert look? (I mean, in all modesty, *another* expert.)

Comment: No, not really. You get a look at your question from the users and can only hope for an "expert" to drop by. Awarding a bounty might get more attention, but not particularly from an "expert".

Comment: In general, this question is not too much different from the old *"How do I ping Jon Skeet and get him to look at my problem?"* question, for which the answer is *"You can't and don't"*.

Comment: I think it could be an interesting feature - since I discovered SO, this is one of the rare time I'd like to use that right! (ie not abusing it). Feature *not* being "call Skeet"... but a new Tab "Questions requiring expert look"

Comment: @ring0 And what defines an "expert look"? How is that going to be judged? I would say you can't really judge that. And then you'll end up with something similar to a bounty anyway.

Comment: See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/289691)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to invite experts to take a closer look at your question is chat, *if* there's an appropriate chat room. Fortunately, for computer science, we not only have appropriate chat rooms, but two Stack Exchange 2.0 sites:

- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

I'd start by dropping the question in [Computer Science's main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2710/computer-science), don't ping anyone directly, just drop the question and explain your concerns, I'm sure one of the regulars will eventually get back at you. Just keep in mind that SE 2.0 sites don't get as much traffic as SO, you'll might have to wait a couple of days for a response.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Actually I started a chat with the person, but seemingly he was in a bad faith mood. Not used much to the chats yet...

Comment: @ring0 if by "bad faith mood" you mean "didn't want to be pestered in chat about looking at somebody's question", you're going to have to live with that possibility. Experts on SE sites volunteer their time, most of them aren't terribly fond of being directly. Just present your issue in chat and if somebody is willing to help, they will get back to you

Comment: @Pekka this is not what I mean. I was in a chat room with the person wrongly answering the question - when (I think) I demonstrated where the problem was in his answer, he could not admit it, using incorrect arguments - this is what I call "bad faith mood"

Comment: @ring0 ah, okay. That's something different.

Comment: Update: it happens the guy answered correctly and I was wrong, so I forgot my weird *printf* prejudice and took some rest..